# How to create a 2 column layout in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: html, css, polymer

How do I create a two-column layout in Polymer 1.0?

Comment: This question aims to get an answer in form of source code or a link to API docs of Polymer.  Can you describe why you think I expect to find a book, tool, software library, tutorial ?

Comment: This question is on-topic. Please reopen.

Comment: Please reopen, and remove some reputation points from the person who closed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout).

You just need to define a *horizontally laid out* `div` and then use `flex` to decide how much portion you want for each inner `div`.

```
  <div class="horizontal layout" style="height:100%">
    <div class="flex-1">
      Left column
    </div>
    <div class="flex-4">
      Right column
    </div>
  </div>
```

Check out a live sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0IRTGMntrJlp3kmAusEa?p=preview).

Comment: be sure to import `iron-flex-factors`

Comment: @dman looks like custom CSS properties are the way to go now?